# Xlwings addin works but fails to update as I change underlying code

Tags: python-3.x, add-in, xlwings

I have downloaded xlwings addin to launch some python scripts from a VBA macro. My python version is 3.7 , 64-bit and I work in a sublime environment.
I've defined:

1. HelloWorld24 VBA macro on a Example.xlsm workbook which runs a
2. working_test.py script that changes the workbook

Note that the workbook and the script are in the same folder. If I run HelloWorld24, working_test.py runs as expected and Example.xlsm is changed correspondingly. So far so good. However, if I change working_test.py, save it and run HelloWorld24 again, Example.xlsm does not change. I've cleared Example.xlsm, ran the macro again and get the same result as in the first run.

1.I don' think this is a problem with VBA as if I change the non-run python part of HelloWorld24, Example.xlsm is changed correspondingly (for example below if I change 912 to 1000 in the second line of the macro).

2.Also, if I create a new python script and a new macro, the addin works as expected as it takes into accoutn the changes in the underlying python file.

3.It seems to me that once run, the addin freezes the python script to its first version and I can't find a way to refresh it short of creating a new python file with a different name.

4.Even if I introduce errors in the working_test.py file, the VBA macro runs fine.

5.Conversely, if I create a macro on a file that has python errors, I will always receive the error message from VBA even if I correct the underlying errors in the python file.

```py
#working_test.py
def world():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = 'Hello World!'
```

```py
#VBA macro
Sub HelloWorld24()
RunPython ("import working_test; working_test.world()")
Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + 912
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if I delete the macro, save the workbook, change the python script's content and recreate an identical macro, the python code runs through the addin as it ran in the original macro.

Comment: When I use the sample xlwings 'myproject files', I do not encounter this error. Will investigate.